# rlang::missing_arg() is not recognized as missing with a summarise() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am trying to pass a possibly-missing argument (w in `weighted.mean`) to a function called within `summarise`.

While using `rlang::missing_arg()` works outside of `summarise`, it is not recognized anymore as missing inside `summarise`?

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

fo_is_missing <- function(w) missing(w)

fo_is_missing()
#> [1] TRUE

var <- missing_arg()
fo_is_missing(w=var)
#> [1] TRUE

iris %>% 
  summarise(mean = fo_is_missing(w= var))
#>    mean
#> 1 FALSE
```

##### Real case example:

summarizing with `weighted.mean` with/without weight argument:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
var <- missing_arg()
summarise(iris, mean = weighted.mean(Petal.Length, w= var))
#> Error in `summarise()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `mean = weighted.mean(Petal.Length, w = var)`.
#> Caused by error in `weighted.mean.default()`:
#> ! argument "var" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Try `summarize(iris, mean = !!fo_is_missing())`.

Comment: nice! Want to write it as an answer, and give some explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Mmh, actually it doesn't seem to work in a just slightly more general context, I've updated the question accordingly: `var <- missing_arg(); summarise(iris, mean = !!weighted.mean(Petal.Length, w= var))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a workaround.

Using `ifelse` in conjunction with `rlang::is_missing`

```
library(dplyr)

summarize_missing <- function(x, variable) 
  summarize(x, mean = ifelse(!!rlang::is_missing(variable), 
    weighted.mean(Petal.Length, w=), weighted.mean(Petal.Length, w=variable)))
```

Using `summarize_missing`

```
# missing
var <- rlang::missing_arg()

summarize_missing(iris, var)
   mean
1 3.758
```

```
# setting values
set.seed(42)
var <- sample(1:10, nrow(iris), replace=T)

summarize_missing(iris, var)
      mean
1 3.803673
```